# How to add rectangle or other symbols before section name？

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec, sections-paragraphs, amssymb

[image]

This is what I want.

MWE for test：

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\begin{document}
    \section{section I}
        \subsection{subsection I}
    \section{section II}
        \subsection{subsection II}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have a solution， that suitable for most documentclass.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that also shows which documetclass you are using?

Comment: @samcarter just normal `article` class, I would like to have a general solution, that suitable for most documentclass

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already added `titlesec` to your tags, so you could use this package. For example like this:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{\textcolor{orange}{\rule[-3pt]{5pt}{1em}}}{5pt}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{section I}
        \subsection{subsection I}
    \section{section II}
        \subsection{subsection II}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For example into `stix` (or `fontawesome`) fonts there are many nice symbols. I add a alternative MWE for your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}

\def\orr{\rlap{\protect\makebox[-2cm]{$\color{orange}\vrectangleblack$}}}

\begin{document}
\section{\orr section I}
        \subsection{subsection I}
    \section{\orr section II}
        \subsection{subsection II}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why I have had a negative down? Can I have an explanation?

Comment: +1 from me - nice approach.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner First of all, I thank you for your vote. With so much sincerity in this period I'm getting negative votes without understanding the cause. Thanks again.

Comment: I do not see any reason for a down vote.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I would not tell you a lie and I do not want to make controversy. I remember well that in the chat you have positively voted me before my negative answer without a motivation. I create something simple and I'm not as good as you and many others.

Comment: This messes up bookmarks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWfb4.png

Comment: @samcarter I have not understood. What is the exaplanation of the image?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my comment: I was a good comment. I am not a pro either :).

Comment: I think @samcarter means that your approach creates some negative effects on the PDF bookmarks (the `[-2cm]` bit).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I expressed myself badly. There was a discussion in chat for my negative votes and you to calm the waters you voted for me positively :-). I understood that yours was a good comment. And I think you think that my approach creates some negative effects on the PDF bookmarks (the [-2cm] bit)? I consider it insignificant and I did not even know this.

Comment: @samcarter found out that your approach has a side effect, not me :). And good, that we are on the same page and understand each other. I like the community.

Comment: nice approach, thanks a lot.. for the negative down,  I also cannot explain...

Comment: @sun0727 Thank you so much from the heart. Unfortunately, some users do not appreciate what I write. Patience. I personally do what I can and my negative votes are very few. Maybe for almost two years I have been negating 3 or 4 negatively.